# Alter/Update Stored Procedure

Tags: advantage-database-server

I have a couple of SQL files containing script to alter different stored procedures. The Advantage Server is installed and running on the machine, but the Architect (ARC32.exe) isn't.

How would I be able to run those scripts without the architect?

(I have updated my question to make it clear to everyone, although I have already got the answer by @Mark Wilkins)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just run it from your code (which is what ARC32 does)?

Comment: I don't think that option is implemented in the application to allow us to execute queries

Comment: In *what* application? If you don't have a way (from anywhere) to run the ALTER PROCEDURE statement, you can't run the ALTER PROCEDURE statement. I think you need to [edit] your question and make it much more clear what you're asking.

Comment: By Advantage Architect, I am referring to ARC32. This is not installed on our client's machine. So can I update the procedure without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using v11.x, the [SQL command line utility](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?master_sql_command_line_utility_overview.htm) is another possibility. It is a standalone application that should be simple to copy from one place to another. Assuming that some Advantage client is installed on the machine in question, I believe you would only need the command line utility binary itself (asqlcmd.exe).

A simple way of using it would be to put the [ALTER PROCEDURE](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/master_create_procedure.htm) statement in a text file and then run a statement such as:

```
asqlcmd -CS "Data Source=\\server\path\thedatabase.add;User ID=adssys" -i somefile.sql
```